# Get all values in randomly selected JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, object, random

I'm retrieving a list of objects from a json call. They are quotes with values of 'Author' and 'Text'. Here is a small sample.

```
0:
author: "Thomas Edison"
text: "Genius is one percent inspiration and ninety-nine percent perspiration."
__proto__: Object
1:
author: "Yogi Berra"
text: "You can observe a lot just by watching."
__proto__: Object
```

Then I am selecting a random object from the list. I cant figure out how to get both values from the selected object. I can get text and author separately but I cant seem to get them both

these do work

```
data[ Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length) ]['text']
data[ Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length) ]['author']
```

I tried these and neither work

```
data[ Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length) ]['author','text']
data[ Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length) ]['author'],['text']
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can get the object first, and then get the text and author values:

```
var obj = data[ Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length) ];

console.log(obj.text, obj.author);
```

But using this:

```
data[ Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length) ]['text']
data[ Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length) ]['author']
```

will probably get you a wrong `(text, author)` pair, e.g. it could get you the pair `("You can observe a lot just by watching.", "Thomas Edison")`, which is incorrect, because the object being selected when getting the text might be different from the one being selected when getting the author, this is because calling `Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)` twice will probably give different results for each call.

Answer (score 0):

In your approach you are generating random choice for each author and quote selection. Store your random choice in one other variable then select that index from the array.

```
import random
class Quote:
  def __init__(self, author, quote):
    self.author = author
    self.quote = quote

# Get the quotes list from the api call
quote1=Quote('Thomas Edison','Genius is one percent inspiration and ninety-nine percent perspiration.')
quote2=Quote('Yogi Berra','You can observe a lot just by watching.')
quotesList=[quote1,quote2]
####

#Using random number generator to get random choce less than max lenght of fetched list
maxListLen=len(quotesList)-1
randomChoice=random.randint(0, maxListLen)

print(quotesList[randomChoice].author,' ',quotesList[randomChoice].quote)
```